# Table View not formatting properly

Tags: xcode, swift

I have just added a table view for my app settings and for some reason it is not formatting properly.

[image]

The content is set to static cells and the style is grouped. I've tried messing around with a few things but I can't get it to display properly.

This is how it should look:

[image]

If anyone has any ideas as to why this could be happening, I would very much appreciate the advice.

Answer (score 1):

In `ios8` `tableView` has dynamic content.Use `rowHeight` explicitly to define rowHeight in your code

```
self.yourTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44;
self.yourTableView.rowHeight = 44;
```

if you want to not use auto layout.Write this in `viewDidLoad`

or

add constraints to your tableViewCells simplet way is to add from constraint inspector as `reset to suggested constraints`

[image]

and write in `viewDidLoad`

```
 tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44
 tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

Comment: Unfortunately after adding that line of code there is now just a blank screen.

Comment: I'm still using Beta 3 at the moment.

Comment: Go to your tableViewCell and add layouts as requestToSuggested constraints from constraints inspector and try ` tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 89
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension`

Comment: Sorry, how do I add this? At the moment under 'Constraints' it just says "This view has no constraints".

Comment: Have your autoLayout `on` can you check in storyBoard??

Comment: try to use this in `viewDidAppear` it should work `self.yourTableView.rowHeight = 44;`

Comment: Yeah, autoLayout is on.

Comment: Putting the code in viewDidAppear didn't fix the issue. Still have a blank screen.

Comment: replace that properties with edited answer i.e  `tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44
 tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension` and than reset to suggested constraints

Comment: Still a blank screen. I've updated my original question with an image of what it should look like if it helps at all.

Comment: can you upload link of source code if it is not any problem?

Comment: Thanks for your help! I've just sorted the issue by redoing the table view and changing the cell style from custom to one of the other styles.